# EC2 user-data and private s3 resources

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I would like to set a user-data script on my EC2 instances like this:

```
#include
http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myapp/environment/aws_init.sh
```

However the resource is acl private and cannot be accessed without credentials.

There are multiple solutions to this issue, such as using curl modified to compute credentials to append in a request or tools like s3cmd, all of which reads credentials stored somewhere.

I would like to know if IAM can help here, given this is a autoscale configuration, in getting and executing this file.

I was reading here: http://aws.amazon.com/iam/

> **Introducing roles for EC2 instances**
>
> Roles for EC2 instances is a new
> feature that makes it easier for you to securely access AWS services
> from within your EC2 instances. It ensures that you automatically will
> have valid AWS access keys on your EC2 instances, and makes it easier
> for you to control the AWS service permissions you want to grant to
> applications running on your EC2 instances. To the right is a short
> video that illustrates how easy it is to get started. Visit the
> Working with roles section in the Using IAM guide for more details.

Will it work in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once a IAM role has been set one can perform a GET to the appropriate internal endpoint to get the credentials, so the answer is yes.

Hope it helps someone else.